# Flex List ItemRenderer with TextInput recycle

Tags: flash, apache-flex, flexbuilder

I had list itemrenderer with textinputs, but when i write something in the text input, the other will get the same value. I used to set the useVirtualLayout to false, but really decrease the performance of the list. I putting only the "data.value" to labels. Any way to turn this issue off? Ty

Comment: When you write something in a TextInput what others get the same value?  How and where are you using data.value?  Turning off useVirtualLayout can decrease performance because a renderer is created for every element in the dataProvider, instead of just the elements shown on the screen.

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply! I using it on the itemrenderer.mxml, using like that <s:label text="{data.question}" /> and there is the text input box <s:TextInput id="answer" />. When i write something in this first textinput, when i roll down the scroll the sixth is with the same value of the first, and if i update the sixth the first get the updated value; i not using any action script file, doing it on the load of the itemrenderer.